Why is my AutoCompleteTextView in Android Studio not working using an API?
The list of book titles that I retrieve with my Google Books API are not displayed as suggestions:
here is the xml code of the title field :
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/titleTil"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/languageTil"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                app:hintEnabled="false"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/titleEt"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_title_gray"
                    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                    android:hint="Title"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/gray01"
                    android:importantForAccessibility="yes" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

and my activity.java code :

public class AddBookActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ActivityAddBookBinding binding;

    private ArrayAdapter<String> bookTitleAdapter;

    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityAddBookBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        setupBookTitleAutoComplete();
        
        bookTitleAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, bookTitles);
        AutoCompleteTextView titleAutoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) binding.titleTil.getEditText();
        titleAutoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(bookTitleAdapter);

        titleAutoCompleteTextView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (s.length() > 2) { 
                    Log.d("AddBookActivity", "Text changed, starting fetchBooks");
                    fetchBooks(s.toString(), binding.languageEt.getText().toString());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });

        titleAutoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener((adapterView, view, position, id) -> {
            String selectedTitle = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Log.d("AddBookActivity", "Item selected: " + selectedTitle);
            fetchBookDetails(selectedTitle, binding.languageEt.getText().toString());
        });
    }

    private void fetchBooks(String query, String language) {
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                String apiKey = "mykey"; 
                String baseUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes";
                String langRestrict = LANGUAGE_CODES[getLanguageIndex(language)];
                String urlStr = baseUrl + "?q=" + URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF-8") + "&langRestrict=" + langRestrict + "&maxResults=10" + "&key=" + apiKey;
                Log.d("AddBookActivity", "Fetching books with URL: " + urlStr);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(urlStr).openConnection();
                try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()))) {
                    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        response.append(line);
                    }
                    Log.d("AddBookActivity", "Response received: " + response.toString());
                    runOnUiThread(() -> updateBookSuggestions(response.toString()));
                } finally {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("AddBookActivity", "Error fetching books", e);
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private void fetchBookDetails(String title, String language) {
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                String apiKey = "my key"; 
                String baseUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes";
                String langRestrict = LANGUAGE_CODES[getLanguageIndex(language)];
                String query = title + "+intitle:" + title;
                String urlStr = baseUrl + "?q=" + URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF-8") + "&langRestrict=" + langRestrict + "&maxResults=1" + "&key=" + apiKey;
                Log.d("AddBookActivity", "Fetching book details with URL: " + urlStr);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(urlStr).openConnection();
                try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()))) {
                    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        response.append(line);
                    }
                    Log.d("AddBookActivity", "Detailed response received: " + response.toString());
                    runOnUiThread(() -> updateBookDetails(response.toString()));
                } finally {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("AddBookActivity", "Error fetching book details", e);
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private void updateBookSuggestions(String json) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
            JSONArray items = jsonObject.getJSONArray("items");
            bookTitles.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(items.length(), 10); i++) {
                JSONObject book = items.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject volumeInfo = book.getJSONObject("volumeInfo");
                bookTitles.add(volumeInfo.getString("title"));
            }
            bookTitleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("AddBookActivity", "Failed to parse book data", e);
        }
    }


    private void updateBookSuggestions(String json) {
        Log.d("AddBookActivity", "Updating book suggestions with JSON: " + json);
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
            JSONArray items = jsonObject.getJSONArray("items");
            bookTitles.clear();
            if (items.length() == 0) {
                Log.d("AddBookActivity", "No items found in JSON response");
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < items.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject book = items.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONObject volumeInfo = book.getJSONObject("volumeInfo");
                    String title = volumeInfo.getString("title");
                    bookTitles.add(title);
                    Log.d("AddBookActivity", "Added book title: " + title);
                }
                Log.d("AddBookActivity", "Total books added: " + bookTitles.size());
            }
            runOnUiThread(() -> {
                bookTitleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                AutoCompleteTextView titleAutoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) binding.titleTil.getEditText();
                titleAutoCompleteTextView.requestFocus();
                if (titleAutoCompleteTextView.getText().length() >= titleAutoCompleteTextView.getThreshold()) {
                    titleAutoCompleteTextView.showDropDown();
                }

            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("AddBookActivity", "Failed to parse book data", e);
        }
    }

    private void loadImageIntoView(String imageUrl) {
        Glide.with(this).load(imageUrl).into(binding.coverImageView);
    }

    private void setupBookTitleAutoComplete() {
        bookTitleAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, bookTitles);
        AutoCompleteTextView titleAutoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) binding.titleTil.getEditText();
        titleAutoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(bookTitleAdapter);
        titleAutoCompleteTextView.setAccessibilityDelegate(new View.AccessibilityDelegate() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(View host, AccessibilityNodeInfo info) {
                super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host, info);
                info.setText("Enter book title. Suggestions will appear as you type.");
            }
        });

        titleAutoCompleteTextView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (s.length() > 2) {
                    fetchBooks(s.toString(), binding.languageEt.getText().toString());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });
    }
}

If I type 'Mistborn' on the title field. I have this on my log :
D/AddBookActivity: Response received: {  "kind": "books#volumes",  "totalItems": 283,  "items": [    {      "kind": "books#volume",      "id": "t_ZYYXZq4RgC",      "etag": "O9goLPs+zIw",      "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/t_ZYYXZq4RgC",      "volumeInfo": {        "title": "Mistborn",        "subtitle": "The Final Empire",        "authors": [          "Brandon Sanderson"        ],        "publisher": "Macmillan",        "publishedDate": "2010-04-01",        "description": "Now with over 10 million copies sold, The Mistborn Series has the thrills of a heist story, the twistiness of political intrigue, and the epic scale of a landmark fantasy saga. For a thousand years the ash fell and no flowers bloomed. For a thousand years the Skaa slaved in misery and lived in fear. For a thousand years the Lord Ruler, the \"Sliver of Infinity,\" reigned with absolute power and ultimate terror, divinely invincible. Then, when hope was so long lost that not even its memory remained, a terribly scarred, heart-broken half-Skaa rediscovered it in the depths of the Lord Ruler's most hellish prison. Kelsier \"snapped\" and found in himself the powers of a Mistborn. A brilliant thief and natural leader, he turned his talents to the ultimate caper, with the Lord Ruler himself as the mark. Kelsier recruited the underworld's elite, the smartest and most trustworthy allomancers, each of whom shares one of his many powers, and all of whom relish a high-stakes challenge. Only then does he reveal his ultimate dream, not just the greatest heist in history, but the downfall of the divine despot. But even with the best criminal crew ever assembled, Kel's plan looks more like the ultimate long shot, until luck brings a ragged girl named Vin into his life. Like him, she's a half-Skaa orphan, but she's lived a much harsher life. Vin has learned to expect betrayal from everyone she meets, and gotten it. She will have to learn to trust, if Kel is to help her master powers of which she never dreamed. This saga dares to ask a simple question: What if the hero of prophecy fails? Other Tor books by Brandon Sanderson The Cosmere The Stormlight Archive The Way of Kings Words of Radiance Edgedancer (Novella) Oathbringer The Mistborn trilogy Mistborn: The Final Empire The Well of Ascension The Hero of Ages Mistborn: The Wax and Wayne series Alloy of Law Shadows of Self Bands of Mourning Collection Arcanum Unbounded Other Cosmere novels Elantris Warbreaker The Alcatraz vs. the Evil Librarians series Alcatraz vs. the Evil Librarians The Scrivener's Bones The Knights of Crystallia The Shattered Lens The Dark Talent The Rithmatist series The Rithmatist Other books by Brandon Sanderson The Reckoners Steelheart Firefight Calamity At the Publisher's request, this title is being sold without Digital Rights Management Software (DRM) applied.",        "industryIdentifiers": [          {            "type": "ISBN_13",            "identifier": "9781429914567"          },          {            "type": "ISBN_10",            "identifier": "1429914564"          }        ],        "readingModes": {          "text": true,          "image": false        },        "pageCount": 686,        "printType": "BOOK",        "categories": [          "Fiction"        ],        "averageRating": 4.5,        "ratingsCount": 78,        "maturityRating": "NOT_MATURE",        "allowAnonLogging": true,        "contentVersion": "14.44.38.0.preview.2",        "panelizationSummary": {          "containsEpubBubbles": false,          "containsImageBubbles": false        },        "imageLinks": {          "smallThumbnail": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=t_ZYYXZq4RgC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&edge=curl&source=gbs_api",          "thumbnail": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=t_ZYYXZq4RgC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api"        },        "language": "en",        "previewLink": "http://books.google.be/books?id=t_ZYYXZq4RgC&pg=PA637&dq=mistbor&hl=&cd=1&source=gbs_api",        "infoLink": "https://play.google.
D/AddBookActivity: Updating book suggestions with JSON: {  "kind": "books#volumes",  "totalItems": 283,  "items": [    {      "kind": "books#volume",      "id": "t_ZYYXZq4RgC",      "etag": "O9goLPs+zIw",      "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/t_ZYYXZq4RgC",      "volumeInfo": {        "title": "Mistborn",        "subtitle": "The Final Empire",        "authors": [          "Brandon Sanderson"        ],        "publisher": "Macmillan",        "publishedDate": "2010-04-01",        "description": "Now with over 10 million copies sold, The Mistborn Series has the thrills of a heist story, the twistiness of political intrigue, and the epic scale of a landmark fantasy saga. For a thousand years the ash fell and no flowers bloomed. For a thousand years the Skaa slaved in misery and lived in fear. For a thousand years the Lord Ruler, the \"Sliver of Infinity,\" reigned with absolute power and ultimate terror, divinely invincible. Then, when hope was so long lost that not even its memory remained, a terribly scarred, heart-broken half-Skaa rediscovered it in the depths of the Lord Ruler's most hellish prison. Kelsier \"snapped\" and found in himself the powers of a Mistborn. A brilliant thief and natural leader, he turned his talents to the ultimate caper, with the Lord Ruler himself as the mark. Kelsier recruited the underworld's elite, the smartest and most trustworthy allomancers, each of whom shares one of his many powers, and all of whom relish a high-stakes challenge. Only then does he reveal his ultimate dream, not just the greatest heist in history, but the downfall of the divine despot. But even with the best criminal crew ever assembled, Kel's plan looks more like the ultimate long shot, until luck brings a ragged girl named Vin into his life. Like him, she's a half-Skaa orphan, but she's lived a much harsher life. Vin has learned to expect betrayal from everyone she meets, and gotten it. She will have to learn to trust, if Kel is to help her master powers of which she never dreamed. This saga dares to ask a simple question: What if the hero of prophecy fails? Other Tor books by Brandon Sanderson The Cosmere The Stormlight Archive The Way of Kings Words of Radiance Edgedancer (Novella) Oathbringer The Mistborn trilogy Mistborn: The Final Empire The Well of Ascension The Hero of Ages Mistborn: The Wax and Wayne series Alloy of Law Shadows of Self Bands of Mourning Collection Arcanum Unbounded Other Cosmere novels Elantris Warbreaker The Alcatraz vs. the Evil Librarians series Alcatraz vs. the Evil Librarians The Scrivener's Bones The Knights of Crystallia The Shattered Lens The Dark Talent The Rithmatist series The Rithmatist Other books by Brandon Sanderson The Reckoners Steelheart Firefight Calamity At the Publisher's request, this title is being sold without Digital Rights Management Software (DRM) applied.",        "industryIdentifiers": [          {            "type": "ISBN_13",            "identifier": "9781429914567"          },          {            "type": "ISBN_10",            "identifier": "1429914564"          }        ],        "readingModes": {          "text": true,          "image": false        },        "pageCount": 686,        "printType": "BOOK",        "categories": [          "Fiction"        ],        "averageRating": 4.5,        "ratingsCount": 78,        "maturityRating": "NOT_MATURE",        "allowAnonLogging": true,        "contentVersion": "14.44.38.0.preview.2",        "panelizationSummary": {          "containsEpubBubbles": false,          "containsImageBubbles": false        },        "imageLinks": {          "smallThumbnail": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=t_ZYYXZq4RgC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&edge=curl&source=gbs_api",          "thumbnail": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=t_ZYYXZq4RgC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api"        },        "language": "en",        "previewLink": "http://books.google.be/books?id=t_ZYYXZq4RgC&pg=PA637&dq=mistbor&hl=&cd=1&source=gbs_api",        "infoLink": "ht
D/AddBookActivity: Added book title: Mistborn
D/AddBookActivity: Added book title: The Hero of Ages
D/AddBookActivity: Added book title: A Royal Embarrassment
D/AddBookActivity: Added book title: Warbreaker
D/AddBookActivity: Added book title: Continue Online The Complete Series
D/AddBookActivity: Added book title: Mistborn Trilogy Boxed Set
D/AddBookActivity: Added book title: The Bands of Mourning
D/AddBookActivity: Added book title: Mistborn: Secret History
D/AddBookActivity: Added book title: Study Guide - Misborn
D/AddBookActivity: Added book title: Oathbringer
D/AddBookActivity: Total books added: 10

I would like the user to choose the language of the book first and while they are writing on the title field, they will see suggestions from the book corresponding to the title they are putting. He will select one of the suggestions, so the other fields of the book will be filled with the info that book.

What do you mean by "not working"? What do you expect and what do you actually get?

The suggestions of books are not showing up. I would like the user when writing a book title, there are suggestions for books that have the same title, using my Google books Api. At the moment there are only api calls that work in the logs but it is impossible to retrieve the titles of these books and display them as suggestions.

Tips to debug 1. try supplying some constant strings to bookTitles to ensure the AutoCompleteTextView itself works 2. Put break points or Log inside updateBookSuggestions to ensure it has run and examine the content of bookTitles after update


i create a new test in my xml AutoCompleteTextView and added this code private void setupTestAutoComplete() {      ArrayAdapter<String> testAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,              android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,              new String[]{"Test Book 1", "Test Book 2", "Test Book 3"});      AutoCompleteTextView testAutoCompleteTextView = binding.testTitleEt;      testAutoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(testAdapter);  } and it is working.


Did you check if you get response correctly from the api?


i used logs on my method udpateBookSuggestions and yes it shows me some titles but only on logs and it is not displaying.


(1) I got my reponse from the api correctly i modified my updateBookSuggestions method with : private void updateBookSuggestions(String json) {         Log.d("AddBookActivity", "Updating book suggestions with JSON: " + json);         try {             JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);             JSONArray items = jsonObject.getJSONArray("items");             bookTitles.clear();             if (items.length() == 0) {                

(2) Log.d("AddBookActivity", "No items found in JSON response");             }             for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(items.length(), 10); i++) {                 JSONObject book = items.getJSONObject(i);                 JSONObject volumeInfo = book.getJSONObject("volumeInfo");                 String title = volumeInfo.getString("title");                 bookTitles.add(title);                 Log.d("AddBookActivity", "Added book title: " + title);      

Maybe since the suggestion is triggered when text change, but your text change trigger the fetch, so by the time your book list is fetched, there is no text change to trigger the suggestion check. Try adding testAutoCompleteTextView.setText(testAutoCompleteTextView.getText().toString()) after bookTitleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

You can Edit your post if you have additional code to post, instead of writing messy code in comment.

(3)}             bookTitleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();             Log.d("AddBookActivity", "Adapter notified of data change.");         } catch (Exception e) {             Log.e("AddBookActivity", "Failed to parse book data", e);         }     } so it shows me those titles, if i write Mistborn on the title field : D/AddBookActivity: Added book title: Mistborn D/AddBookActivity: Added book title: The Hero of Ages D/AddBookActivity: Added book title: A Royal Embarrassment D/AddBookActivity: Added book title: Warbreaker 

thank you for taking your time to solve this issue but the suggestions still don't appear.
